# .htaccess redirect request from specific domain to another domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have an apache server hosting a site. I have 2 domains pointing to this server, www.mysite.se and www.mysite.com.

I'm trying to figure out how to in the htaccess file to redirect traffic coming from the www.mysite.se domain to www.mysite.com/se/

I've tried several ways but cannot get it to work. I always just end up on the root of the site, as in www.mysite.com instead of the /se/ path.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www\.mysite\.se [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/se/ [R=301,NC]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.se$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /se/$1

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.se$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ se [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have finally done it!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mysite.se$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/se/ [R=301,L]
```